# Does Mik need eye contact in order to hypnotize?

Tags: tintin

In *Flight 714*, Mik can communicate using telepathy, without needing eye contact.

For example, here Mik is not present in the scene, but is able to talk to Tintin:

[image]

However, he tells Carreidas "*Look straight at me!*". Therefore, eye contact seems to be a requirement in order to hypnotize.

[image]

[image]

However, there is no eye contact when he hypnotizes the bad guys.

[image]

Why is that? Did Hergé explain it? I have some ideas:

- The bad guys aren't looking at him, but are looking at the UFO. And he is inside the UFO. So maybe looking towards him is enough, even if he is hidden.
- Maybe the UFO is also able to hypnotize people that look at it. So Mik could be using UFO's hypnotic powers instead of his own.
- Being in the UFO increases his hypnotic powers, so he does not need eye contact then.
- He never needs eye contact. He only pretends so, e.g. in order to look like less powerful and threatening.

Comment: I got the impression that it was that strange antenna thing on his head (the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_714) describes it as a “telepathic transmitter”), not eye contact. Asking Careidas to look straight at him is just to get him to shut up.

Comment: Yes, the antenna is a requirement. But it seems Mik uses eye contact somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Although I have no evidence to support my answer, I have reread this one and found that while Mik fully hypnotizes somebody 13 times--5 bad guys, 7 good guys, and Carreidas twice--he only requires full eye contact with these people, it seems, two times, with the Captain and with Carreidas.  He also speaks in somebody's head without full hypnosis three times, with Tintin once and the Captain twice.  And only one of these times he needs eye contact.  It seems pretty obvious that eye contact is not needed.  But then why ask Carreidas to look at him?

This is just speculation, but all three times he requires someone to look straight at him to be hypnotized, that person is making some kind of disturbance.  The Captain, of course, not believing in hypnosis and extraterrestrial worlds and that stuff, twice, and Carreidas screaming about his hat.  So maybe, as alexwlchan said, it's just getting Carreidas to shut up.  But this doesn't make as much sense to me as another hypothesis.  Mik just needed the eye contact because either he was being distracted by their blubbering, and it is hard to do while distracted, or the Captain/Carreidas was distracted by their own blubbering/barnacles/hat, and he needed their extra attention to be able to bend them to his will.

We may never know, but I think my hypothesis is a valid one.